# BAT Find text in line > Replace all line

Tags: batch-file, replace, find, line

I have a problem with the bat.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

set "search=time_upper_limit:"
set "replace=time_upper_limit: 9999999"

set "textFile=game.sii"

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%textFile%" ^& break ^> "%textFile%" ') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    >>"%textFile%" echo(!line:%search%=%replace%!
    endlocal
)
```

how to make a .bat ; 
found a line whith text and then replaced the whole line ; 
file has more than 24,000 lines, ; 
It took him almost 20 minutes :( ;
can it be done in faster way? ;

only one line in file to replace

line to replace start by test " time_upper_limit: "

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: This script works as designed. Buy a better computer.

Comment: It is just _one line_ that needs to be replaced? Or may be _several lines_?

Comment: only one line in file

Comment: Are you sure that the decrypted version of your `game.sii` is fully compatible with the search replace you are doing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I cannot see anything wrong with the script you've posted which should cause that sort of run time. *Unless the decryption has somehow messed with the input file*.

If you don't require empty lines to be preserved and `game.sii` is properly decrypted, *(without awkward/poisonous characters)*, something like this should also work:

```bat
@Echo Off
Ren "game.sii" "game.bak"
(For /F "UseBackQ EOL=: Tokens=1* Delims=:" %%A In ("game.bak"
) Do If "%%A"==" time_upper_limit" (Echo= time_upper_limit: 9999999
    ) Else If "%%B"=="" (Echo=%%A) Else Echo=%%A:%%B)>game.sii
```

***FootNote:*** Changing your saved game settings is cheating.

Comment: This code does not work correctly with my file

Comment: My code is only as good as the information you have provided. If you have a 'clean' file with a line beginning with `time_upper_limit:` it will replace that entire line with `time_upper_limit: 9999999`. Your initial code performs a string replacement, this code performs a line replacement. If the former works and not the latter, I'd suggest that the information you have provided is lacking. If you believe my code to be wrong, please tell me what's wrong with it, if the result or it's running is not correct then debugging is impossible without further information.

Comment: BTW, after having now seen your `game.sii` file I have updated my code accordingly. I was correct that your information was lacking, _the line you were searching should have began with a single space_.

Comment: Thank you for your help
everything works great

Answer (score 0):

I tried to change the line this code and overwriting a file

```
set findtext="time_upper_limit: "
set replace=time_upper_limit: 9999999"
set findfile="game.sii"
findstr %findtext% %findfile%
```

[game.sii](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5V73QOlO8u6Ni1DNGZCYnFWOTA)